# How can I resolve this SQL / C# DLL conflict

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, server, connection

I have developed an application using C# (Visual Studio) which runs without issue on my Windows 10 development PC. However, when I copy the application to its intended target PC and run it (Server 2012 R2), I get an exception informing me that a file or assembly could not be loaded: **Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=13.100.0.0.**

If I copy version 13 of the dll to the program directory of the target PC and run the app, I then get an exception informing me that it cannot find version 14 of the dll. Copying version 14 to the target then give me the original exception, and so on.

I have references to all the required dlls in the application, namely:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll (the one which is giving me
  the issue). Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
  Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll
  Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

All are set as: specific version = false.

All of the necessary frameworks are installed on the server. Additionally, the following is also installed on the server, which the program interacts with:

•   ColdFusion

•   SQL Server 2012 (and 2008 but this instance is not used by the program)

The .exe is installed via an installer and that installation includes the necessary dlls, which are installed in the same directory as the exe.

Full permissions are available on the directory, and the program itself has the highest access level.

The connection string is selectable by the user and defaults to the correct one, depending on where the program is installed.

Does anyone have any ideas which may help me to resolve this conflict?

Thanking everyone in advance.

Regards,
Ken.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

The version number of Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll shown within Visual Studio is 13.100.0.0. I copied the DLL from the path shown in properties, to the program directory. Guess what? When I ran the program an exception informed me that it could not find version 14.100.0.0!

This is the version of the same DLL as shown on the file's Properties page: 13.0.16106.4.

Answer (score 4):

SMO is always installed in the GAC, so it doesn't matter what files you copy to your /bin folder.  GAC'd assemblies override local ones.

You have referenced the SQL 2016 version of SMO.  So you must either install that on your target server, or build you project against the version of SMO already present on the target server.

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/files-and-version-numbers

Note that because of the hassles with loading and deploying SMO, and SMO's really old API style, it's often better to have your app perform SQL Server administration with just TSQL and System.Data.SqlClient.

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED]

Dumbassary was afoot.

I removed all the references from the Visual Studio project, re-added them and it worked.

The issue was caused by a DLL reference which was pointing to the program's installation directory and not to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies. As the Properties box was not fully expanded, I failed to notice it.

Hopefully, someone else can benefit from my experience.

Thank you for your comment David.